# Confused as to why my PHP include isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, include

I had a prototype of my website working correctly, meaning it connected to the database correctly.  This was done with just one file called "connect.php" which had mysql_connect() and such inside it.  I then separated the connect information into to separate files, one containing the account information (account.php) and one containing the connect function (connect.php), with correct information (I triple checked) and it isn't connecting properly.  All I can think of is that I'm not including it the right way. This is what I have in a file:

```
<?php

include('account.php');       
include('connect.php');
include('functions.php');
.....

?>
```

Edit:
I would first like to thank everyone for the down-votes, you're all so supportive.  Secondly, I seemingly fixed my problem by changing single quotes to double quotes with the include() function and a deleted a few excess spaces.  I'm not quite sure how this changed anything, but apparently it had.

Comment: What is it doing instead? What is in these files? Do you have error reporting on and are you getting any errors?

Comment: Copy and paste the error you're seeing, please.

Comment: Only thing I can see wrong is this won't work unless those three files are in the same directory as the file including them.

Comment: This really doesn't tell us anything.  When you debug into the code, what happens?  Where does it deviate from expected behavior?

Comment: in account is all of the account information stored in variables, and in connect it simply attempts to use the variables to connect to the database.  I know it isn't connecting to the database because when I use just one include with all of the account information and the connect function in one file with the exact same information, it connects properly.

Comment: @Sam Do you need to include connect.php before account.php? Seems like account relies on some mySQL stuff.

Comment: @MartyWallace account.php just has the mysql_connect() information stored as variables.  The mysql function is in connect, so does the order seem logical?

Comment: Your structure seems flawed as for code readability I would expect that all mysql related tasks were in connect.php

Comment: Yes, the task is handled in connect.php but the variables that connect.php uses are stored in account.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include executes all of the code inside the file right away, and performs exactly as if you were copy-and-pasting the files into the document.  This is different from how C or other languages handle `#include` statements.  Pretend you are copy and pasting your code from those 3 files into one file, in that order... would it work? If not, then the reason *that* isn't working is the same as the reason *this* isn't working.  (Logical sanity check for `include()`)

Comment: Actually, I am uncertain about how "C or other languages" technically handle the include statements except that in the language design of those they use header files that make sure the order of includes doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

based on your description of what's happening and the names of the files i would assume a couple of things:

1. the include file paths are in the same relative directory as the file you're calling the includes from?
2. accounts probably had a dependency to connection and functions, so
   their orders should be swapped like connection, functions, then
   accounts.

but yeah you should have debugging turned on or put echo statements after each include (ie echo "1";exit;) to see which include is failing or causing errors.

just an initial place to start given the provided information.

i hope this helps :)